# Helm3 JSON Schema Validation based on enabled is true or false

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm, jsonschema

I have the following scenario for helm for kubernetes. I am using json schema validator to validate the following

```
autoscaling:
   minReplicas: 1
   maxReplicas: 15
  cpu:
     enabled: true
     targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 80
  memory:
     enabled: false
     targetMemoryUtilizationPercentage: 70
```

What i want is that if memory.enabled is false then user does not have to specify the targetMemoryUtilizationPercentage in values.yaml and if memory.enabled is true then user need to specify targetMemoryUtilizationPercentage in values.yaml and it should be a valid integer. The same is the case for CPU block.
Using if else inside json schema validation has not worked.